# Is there a way to import file name as type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I was making an icon component that uses file name as a prop to grab the correct icon from a directory and display it. Here's an example:

```
<Icon name="close" />
```

It will use close.svg file from icons directory and display it.
What i wanted to do is to make a type that allows name to be only one of the files that are in icons directory. For example, if icons directory looks like this:

[image]

Type should be `"close" | "collapse" | "delete"`.

Is it possible to do something like this?

I couldn't figure out a way to import file names from a directory, so I decided to try a different approach:
I'm using vite's `import.meta.glob` to import all SVG files from a directory, like this:

```
import.meta.glob('../assets/icons/*.svg', { eager: true });
```

It returns an object with modules, where each module is a SVG icon as a React component. I wrote a small vite plugin to add an icon name to every SVG module export, so now every module looks like this:

[image: One of the svg modules]

But return type of `import.meta.glob` is `Record<string, unknown>`, so I can't use `iconName` as type since module type is unknown.

So if there's no way to import file names from a directory, maybe there's a way to use module's export as a type? I'm at a complete loss here, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: TypeScript does not run Vite, so at static analysis time, it does not know the actual result. Hence the module export type is `Record<string, unknown>`. You would need to write a CLI tool (or to find one) that reads your project files structure and generates a `.ts` file with the list of file names as directly a union type of literal strings.